# Using VBA, I want to count the number of rows and then print this in a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

Here's the code I'm using but it's not working

```
Sub CountRowsAndPrintInColumnQ()
    
        Dim last_row As Long
        Dim Result As Long
        Set last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Result = Range("Q1")
        
        Result.Value = last_row
        
    End Sub
```

Essentially, I want it to count the rows and then print the value in Q1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the `Set` from the `last_row` calculation line and change `Dim Result As Long` to `Dim Result as Range`. You could also simply omit the result part entirely and just do `Range("Q1").Value = last_row`. `Set` is used for objects such as ranges, not variables that hold values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also an option

```
Sub CountRowsAndPrintInColumnQ()
         'This will write  column "A"  number of rows into cell Q1
        ActiveSheet.Range("Q1").Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub CountRowsAndPrintInColumnQ()
    Dim Index As Long

    Index = 1
    Do Until Range("A" & Index).Value = ""
        Index = Index + 1
    Loop
    Range("Q1").Value = Index
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this Darren. It works but could you please explain how the 'index' syntax works in this context. I've never seen it combined with a loop before like this.

Comment: The loop starts a the first row, and continues adding 1 to Index variable, until the current row has no value. Then column Q1 value is changed to the index's value.